# How to remove bullets from a list and divide it into columns using css

Tags: css

I am trying to break up the following list into 2 or 3 columns using css:
http://www.101calendartemplates.com/test-nav-plugins/

I have tried the following code but it didn't work:

```html
.lcp_catlist ul
{
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
-moz-column-count: 2;
column-count: 2;
-webkit-column-gap: 40px;
column-gap: 40px;
-moz-column-gap: 40px;
list-style-type: none;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a plugin tho?

Comment: @nicole Welcome to StackOverflow! Please be sure to "[accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)" an answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use `element.class` format in your css.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="lcp_catlist">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul.lcp_catlist {columns: 2; list-style-type: none}
```

Here is a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yr1jg1w2/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I cannot use this since the list is generated by shortcode via the List category posts plugin.

Comment: Great answer. I tested it on the site the op linked and they also will need to override or remove `.entry-content ul > li { list-style-type: disc; }` from `style.css` as well.

Comment: @nicole The HTML in this answer is just a sample. The CSS selector `ul.lcp_catlist` is the important part. It should replace `.lcp_catlist ul` in your provided code.

Answer (score 0):

There is already a nice, concise answer here, but I thought I'd provide a few examples and explain a little more in-depth:

**Current Selector - `.lcp_catlist ul`**

To better understand the problem, let's look at some examples of what your current CSS selector accomplishes with different HTML (please run the snippet below):

```css
.lcp_catlist ul {
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-gap: 40px;
  column-gap: 40px;
  -moz-column-gap: 40px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<h2>Example 1</h2>
<ul class="lcp_catlist" id="lcp_instance_0">
  <li>List Item 1</li>
  <li>List Item 2</li>
</ul>

<h2>Example 2</h2>
<div class="lcp_catlist">
  <ul id="lcp_instance_0">
    <li>List Item 1</li>
    <li>List Item 2</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<h2>Example 3</h2>
<div class="lcp_catlist">
  <div>
    <div>
      <ul id="lcp_instance_0">
        <li>List Item 1</li>
        <li>List Item 2</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Notice how the first example doesn't work as intended? That's because your current selector requires the `<ul>` tag to be somewhere **inside** of some element with `class="lcp_catlist"`. Unfortunately, the first example is what we want to select because it is the most similar to your situation.

**New Selector - `ul.lcp_catlist`**

Notice that the new selector doesn't have a space? That's because the space has meaning in CSS selectors. The space in your original selector tells the browser to "go inside and find any __". We actually want to match both conditions (`ul` and `.lcp_catlist`) on the same element(s).

Let's look at that same example with the new selector:

```css
ul.lcp_catlist {
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-gap: 40px;
  column-gap: 40px;
  -moz-column-gap: 40px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<h2>Example 1</h2>
<ul class="lcp_catlist" id="lcp_instance_0">
  <li>List Item 1</li>
  <li>List Item 2</li>
</ul>

<h2>Example 2</h2>
<div class="lcp_catlist">
  <ul id="lcp_instance_0">
    <li>List Item 1</li>
    <li>List Item 2</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<h2>Example 3</h2>
<div class="lcp_catlist">
  <div>
    <div>
      <ul id="lcp_instance_0">
        <li>List Item 1</li>
        <li>List Item 2</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Final Notes:**

Bullets can be added to an entire list or individual items. You have another CSS rule that selects `li` and adds bullets to those. The solution above fixes the list-level setting, but you will also need to fix this at the item-level.

To fix this, you can find and remove `.entry-content ul > li { list-style-type: disc; }` from `style.css`. If you can't do that, you may override it by adding another CSS rule (watch out for [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)!).

Finally, and I hope this doesn't come across as insulting, but these problems seem to stem from an incomplete education in CSS - these are pretty basic problems. I would recommend that you look into some tutorials/classes if you will be doing this type of work often. It may help avoid frustration in the future.